# Javascript RegEx for Numbers Only (no special characters)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a RegEx that will allow the digits 0-9 ONLY and not special characters.  Is  this an impossibility since pressing Shift + 2 is still a digit?

I've used the following:

```
return /[0-9]|\./.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
```

Which works fine except for the special characters that are still allowed.

Any input would be most helpful.

Comment: why don't you validate the field afterwards? Just check for the value and break the validation if it has other than  a number?

Comment: Just check whether `+input === +input` - if it is not a number then `NaN === NaN` is false.

Comment: @Rafael.IT I'd prefer to prevent the keyPress if it isn't a digit.

Comment: @StefanH Yeah, I meant since I'm pressing the 2 digit key, is it still interpreting it as a digit since it allows me to type it with the RegEx?

Comment: Use `onkeypress` instead of `onkeyup/down`. It'll give you the correct value of the key hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are in the right track. Just add `!event.shiftKey`:

```
return /[0-9]|\./.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)) && !event.shiftKey;
```

There are also `altKey` and `ctrlKey` if you need them.

For `keyCode`s coming form the numeric keypad, you need to compare against the numeric `keyCode` instead of using a Regex:

```
return (/[0-9]|\./.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)) && !event.shiftKey) 
    || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105);
```

This technique can also be used instead of the Regex you are using:

```
return (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 && !event.shiftKey) 
    || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105);
```

See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Adding the event.shiftKey checked helped, but if I type digits on the digit keypad it's not letting anything through.  Is this back to my RegEx being incorrect?

Comment: Using @Diego's suggestion along with changing to `onkeypress` instead of `onkeyup` (as suggested by @Teemu), this now works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your Regex is fine (although it also allows a period '.', but I thought that's what you intended). I edited my answer to include the numeric keypad cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think `/[0-9]/` should work as you say.  It will not match "shift-2", only the exact characters 0, 1, 2, ..., 9.  I think the `|\.` part of your RE is what's hurting you...

Comment: I stripped the end out and it has the same results still.  Allows the special characters.

Comment: OK, well sounds like a dead end.  I will claim, though, that it's something funky related to keypress handling, and not strictly a problem with the RE.  Either way... not helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

```
"^[0-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem i see is that keyCode could be multiple digits, but your regex is just one digit followed by a period.  Perhaps this:

```
return /\d+/.test( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) );
```

What are you doing this for?

Comment: It's for a ZipCode textbox, I've been asked to allow only digits as input.

Comment: @mint, so you are trying to validate on each key press?  You may want to wait until an onBlur and test the whole field.  Then its not using event.keyCode which can get hairy in cross browser.  Furthermore, as zip is very well formed, i would suggest this regex:
`/^\d\d\d\d\d(?:-?\d\d\d\d)$/` which is 5 digits followed by an optional dash and four optional extra digits.